# Python. Получение e-mail сообщения частями

Tags: python, email

На почту приходят сообщения с большими (десятки мегабайт) вложениями. Нужно периодически забирать вложения с определенным именем файла и разбирать их. Проблема в том, что скорость до почтового сервера очень низкая, поэтому постоянно тянуть сообщение целиком плохой вариант, канал забивается. Вопросы:

1. Как распарсить ответ на запрос BODYSTRUCTURE, получить имя файла вложения и номер части
2. Как распарсить ответ на запрос BODY[<номер части>]
3. В правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь?

Подключаюсь по IMAP. Пример ответа BODYSTRUCTURE:

164 (BODYSTRUCTURE ((("text" "plain" ("charset" "utf-8") NIL NIL "base64" 318 5 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("text" "html" ("charset" "utf-8") NIL NIL "base64" 554 9 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "alternative" ("boundary" "------_6729_1182992416_29164") NIL NIL NIL)("application" "octet-stream" ("name" "=?utf-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcVVNSMUNWOFxBcHBEYXRhXExvY2FsXFRlbXBcdjhfQTY=?= =?utf-8?B?MV82YzIueGxz?=") NIL NIL "base64" 8450 NIL ("attachment" ("filename" "=?utf-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcVVNSMUNWOFxBcHBEYXRhXExvY2FsXFRlbXBcdjg=?= =?utf-8?B?X0E2MV82YzIueGxz?=")) NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "------_15890_1182992416_29164") NIL NIL NIL))

Comment: Приведите пример запроса BODYSTRUCTURE и BODY.

Comment: посмотрите на содержимое хотя бы одного e-mail сообщения. Познакомьтесь со структурой MIME сообщения. Определите, как файлы добавлены: как часть самого письма или просто ссылка. Если первое, то определите по какому протоколу к серверу можно подключиться (IMAP, частный web-интерфейс), чтобы можно было не скачивая письма получить meta-информацию, по которой определить качать письмо или нет.